# Want to make a 'Free' version of my existing Android App

Tags: android

I want to make a free version of my *existing and already published app* - I've seen suggestions that I make my existing app a library (by checking "Is Library" in properties) - then reference that library from a unique project for the "Free" version and then another new and unique project for my "Paid" version.

If I do this, both my two new projects will have unique name space/package names, which should  allow me to get past google's restriction of main package name uniqueness. However, will I have any other problems, such as updating all the existing apps that are pre-installed? Will all my current users have to re-install the new version or can I continue to upload a binary with a new name space to an existing app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your current application with a new name or package and check it as a library.
Then use your previous name for the free version.

In you free version, add a link to offer people to upgrade to the paid version.

Like this, existing users will have the free vesion as an update.

Comment: I hope you have some new features, or you plan to remove existing ads from the current version... Otherwise, people will keep the current version.

Comment: Yes, there are new features of the paid version (one of which is the removal of ads) - Thanks for the tip! So simple yet effective.